MOSFET transconductance question
I shared the output characteristic graph for R6520KNX3 N channel MOSFET below. MOSFET is 650 V, 20 A.
I need the transconductance value, it is easy to calculate it from output chracteristics but my aplication is Vds=400 V, Vgs= 12 V, these values are out of scale in the graph.
How can I apply my values onto graph and predict the Id?

Source:https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/discrete/transistor/mosfet/r6520knx3c16-e.pdf

Any application that cares about the performance of the device under those conditions would pretty much instantly fry the device. Are you sure you're looking for the right parameter? Most applications would never expose the part to such a high drain-source voltage when it's fully enhanced (as it would be with 12 V on the gate)--that would correspond to 400 V / 0.2 Ω = 2 kA through the device, and 800 kW of power dissipation (enough to power a whole neighborhood).

400V supply or 400V D-S? That thing won't last a microsecond at those conditions, taken literally. Transconductance doesn't enter into it.

Sir, my aplication is Phase shift full bridge. My primary side rms current of the transformer is 3. 1 A  @ 400 V . I am just trying to find Vgs, miller which is calculated as Vth+Id/gfs given by the texas document.
What should I write for the gfs in this condition ?  @Hearth

Sir, my aplication is Phase shift full bridge. My primary side rms current of the transformer is 3. 1 A @ 400 V . I am just trying to find Vgs, miller which is calculated as Vth+Id/gfs given by the texas document. What should I write for the gfs in this condition ?
@TimWilliams

@Mhan Please don't call me sir. That value of gfs should be the device's transconductance at the drain current under consideration, which you should be able to get from Fig. 9 in the datasheet. However, figure 16 just gives it to you directly (as a typical value, at least).

@Hearth In fact, gm levels off, even at high Vds, and Vgs > Vgs(on). Typically this is Id(max pulsed). Being able to get practically unlimited currents from a small device would be very useful in certain applications... but alas, physics makes us work harder than that.

Mhan: how accurately do you need to know plateau voltage? Also do you know the definition of gfs, how it might be obtained from available information?

@TimWilliams Rather than "levels off" I'd say "exponentially decays" with rising Vgs; it has to reach zero eventually or Rdson would be a meaningless statistic. gm is highly dependent on Vgs below this point, though, hence my comment that you need to consider what the drain current is (i.e. what Vgs is, because Vgs is the primary factor in determining drain current during a switching transient, which is where the plateau voltage is relevant).

@Hearth Bah, I said one thing in there but meant another; Id is what levels off, heh. But yeah, just pointing out that a linear reductio ad absurdum isn't exactly a strong argument here. It is indeed a continuous, one-to-one function (Id(Vgs) is), and this is also a powerful fact: if we don't need an accurate measure of Vgs(plateau), then we can more easily give a bounded range, and work with that instead.

Yes sir, I know the definition of gfs, I used this term in my other aplications before but some datasheets includes detailed graphs and some doesn't. In case of my question, graph is not very usable except the given range. Here my question comes, how should I predict an avarage  gfs value from these unsufficient graphs ? What do you suggest me sir,  to have an avarage gfs value in this condition ?  @TimWilliams

Generally speaking, curves can be extended in this way:

The drain curves saturate quickly beyond VGS so there's no point in showing them.
They do show significant slope within the 5V range shown, so the flats are probably higher than this, but not grossly so.
Lesson: Drain characteristics aren't interesting.
Just as well, we don't know what a particular device will do because VGS(th) varies from 3 to 5V; these curves could be up or down by about a volt (and corresponding ID change) in a given device, and you just don't know until you characterize it.
Lesson: devices are variable.  Don't design to a particular device characteristic.  Design to the average and worst-case conditions as appropriate.
You ask for transconductance at VDS = 400V and ID = 3.1A.  The nearest data we have in this plot are 5.5 to 6V, with VDS extrapolated.  This shows a change of 79 pixels, where 97 pixels is 5A, out of a 0.5V VGS change, or 8.14S.  Since ID is higher than desired, and gfs generally rises with ID, we can take this as an upper limit.
We can also consider the transfer curve, Fig.9.  For VDS ~ 4V, we find around 7.1S.  Notice VGS(th) and gfs vary with temperature too.  Do you know the exact TJ you will be operating at -- at all times?  The answer will not be a single value, but yet another range.
You apparently ask for gfs to solve for VGS(plateau), presumably to calculate IG (on/off) and switching times.  Your application note probably follows this scheme:
 
From: Power MOSFET Basics | International Rectifier Fig.13 (p.12)
These waveforms are simple and easy to calculate; but they are an utter fabrication.  They were, even back in the day when this figure was published, i.e., when planar epitaxial MOSFETs were top technology; junction capacitances have always been pretty steeply nonlinear.
Consider a typical contemporary device, with capacitance curves like so:
 
From: IRF540N | Infineon Fig.5 (p.4)
But the waveforms plotted, can only arise from a device with capacitances like so:

So, you can see how unrealistic that is already.
Sort of; they do show the differing slope of Vgs, due to Ciss being higher at low Vds.  But that doesn't explain how that difference arises: I could draw Ciss sloped, or stepped, but in fact, Cgs is ~constant and it's Cgd that varies with Vds: notice the equal magnitude change in both Ciss and Crss.  But we can't have Cgs constant and Cgd varying without also showing curvature in the Vds slope.  So we again conclude it's an unrealistic figure.
The main takeaway is, as long as Miller's theorem applies, dVds/dt and Ig are related by Crss, but Crss itself is varying during the waveform, so we can't calculate power as trivially as the straight-line figure suggests.
Which again, I assume is what you're after: switching times, and power dissipation.
Capacitances are much more dramatic today.  A recent-ish device has a switching curve actually like so:
 
From: STP19NM50N 1.045mA Gate Charge 400V 30.1 ohm Drain.png (links to my website; own work)
There are four characteristic regions: 
VGS rising, ID zero 
VGS rising slower, VDS falling sharply 
VGS quasi-stable, VDS nearly saturated 
VGS rising, VDS fully saturated
The second region merges into the third if using a CCS load; this is a resistor load so ID increases jointly with VDS falling.
The gross difference is in the timing of VDS vs. ID.
This device has curves like so:
 
From: STP19NM50N Coss Comparison.png (links to my website; own work)
The blue curve is as measured from the above waveform, and red is as fitted; the black curves are the datasheet published values.  (This discrepancy is real, and has an interesting explanation, but goes beyond scope here.)  You can see why the plateau spends most of its time at low Vds: the capacitance is absolutely huge down there, and negligible the rest of the way.
And notice your device shows a similar figure (Fig.14):

The curious student might well find themselves asking a follow-on question:
What Vds (single point, or range!) is appropriate to ask for gfs at [for this purpose]?
For devices like this [modern Superjunction types], evidently it's at low voltages, where most of the time is spent during the plateau.
For older devices, a broad range might apply.  Perhaps a weighted average.  Though again, as Id doesn't change much with Vds in the saturation region, we don't end up with much of a range, and taking a typical value suffices.
Current and capacitance saturation are unrelated, by the way.  Typical SJ devices fall off in capacitance in the 10-50V range (it's gone down over time, newer devices having a lower cut; notice the Rohm part loses 90% of its Crss by merely 14V!).  Id saturation occurs somewhere above Vgs, roughly speaking: perhaps 5-20V.  These ranges overlap now, but the underlying mechanisms are fundamentally different.

But all of this is practically irrelevant.
I wrote this out, to give an explanation of why it's a poor route.  Perhaps I've made my point... perhaps my point is too long and most readers will gloss over it.  But there are many sub-points within, that readers may find of interest.  The MOSFETs of today are wildly different from the assumptions that historical references used with what they had back then.  These references are now outdated.  New methods and new approaches must be learned and understood.  Appnotes cannot be trusted as sources for this information: they are largely drawing from old references (if they even note any references -- most cite nothing at all!).  As has always been the case, you are on your own for evaluating the quality of information before you; everything must be subject to critical analysis, and cross-checked between multiple references, and especially cold hard experimental data.
But there is very little need for VGS(plateau), for capacitance curves, for gfs, at all.
Just use QG(tot).
Use QG(tot) to calculate gate drive capacity (peak current vs. switching speed), drive power, etc.  Use QGD for plateau time.  The exact plateau voltage doesn't much matter: it'll be higher on the rising edge, lower on the falling edge, and yes it depends on ID, but also LS, and assuming a typical value will suffice (perhaps 3-7V here).  Use a modest fraction of QGD for VDS ramp (how much exactly depends on the capacitance ratio, which capacitances are dominant (Coss vs. Crss), and other connected stuff, i.e. the opposing transistors in the respective half-bridges).
That last part in particular is worth concentrating on.  Note that SJ capacitance looks like diode recovery.  It takes place at a "reverse" voltage (that is, reverse with respect to the body diode), not like reverse recovery proper (diode still "on", dropping forward voltage), but over the voltage scales we're working with here, +1V isn't far from -20V, compared to the full swing of 400V.  SJ capacitance might be a true capacitance (it's not, actually, but again, advanced details out of scope), but it still incurs switching loss when we're doing hard switching -- even if the body diode itself isn't activated and we're doing fully synchronous switching.
When load current is enough (high enough magnitude, and inductive phase) to commutate switch node voltage, we have soft switching, and the Coss energy isn't consumed, rather it's shuttled back and forth through the load inductance.  If you can arrange your PSPWM system to act this way, you can get quite low switching losses.
If you can't, I might just as well recommend two-switch forward topology, or something simple like that: if you're spending the hard switching power either way, might as well have an easier time with the overall design, and use a simpler circuit.  Evidently you're switching 400V 3.1A, the power level is not at all remarkable, and a conventional square-pulse forward converter will be much easier to design than a PSPWM, soft switching, or resonant converter is.
In any case, predicting power dissipation is nontrivial, and highly load dependent.  It's difficult to reproduce an accurate switching circuit in SPICE; manufacturer models may not even be representative here.  The triangular-waveform approximation is still useful here, but only to get in the ballpark; a starting point, a worst-case upper bound perhaps, but not representative of actual operating conditions.
Building prototypes, and allowing for worst-case errors in calculations, is recommended.  If high efficiency is a design requirement, iterating over a few prototypes, while varying component values and types, is likely to find much better results -- including in other components that are not easy to calculate, like inductor and transformer core losses.  This will be time (and probably budget) intensive, but that is simply the cost of a highly optimized design.

Your explanations are excellent sir.I was going to ask why you used Vgs of 5.5 to 6V although my Vgs is 12V. As I read your comments, I realized that Vgs miller doesnt matter much. It will change slighly. That is okay.
My second point from your comments is : If I only use Qg-total which means I need Crss-avg, since Crss is changing parameter I need to calculate Crss-avg from the given tables (capacitance - Vds).  Texas doc has a famous way to calculate it from the given values and based on desired application values. ( Crss,avg=2xCrss,spec x sqrt(Vds-spec/Vds-off).  @Tim Williams

Crss is 50 pF aproximately, measured at low Vds = 25V as you mensioned in your comments. I recalculate it using the formula above and Crss-avg is = 25 pF. Now as you mensioned plateu region takes more time due to several reasons. when I calculate 25pF x 400V = 10 nC of charge approximately. This is supposed to be more charge compared to Qgs but in the datasheet Qgs is given as  10 nC, they are so close . shouldn't be Qgd more than Qgs ?  @Tim Williams

Your final Vgs is 12. It has to go through every single fraction of a volt to get there. Around 4-6V is where the interesting stuff happens.  The stuff you asked about. I suggest setting up the basic test circuit (common source switch with resistor or clamped CCS load) and zooming in on the edge, to get familiar with the dynamics. You asked about gm around 3A, which will be around the Vgs mentioned; if you don't know why that's relevant, I mean, you asked, that's up to you.

That Crss,avg formula sounds wrong, I would be quite curious under what justification they publish it. If it's an older (Unitrode?) app note, it's probably related to typical geometry of planar (old) devices. SJ MOS didn't exist back then. If it's a newer appnote, and it doesn't provide any justification, proof or citation of source, I would just as well ignore it: appnotes are a minefield of poor quality information, occasionally useful beyond their narrow purpose and not a reliable method of learning.

Okay Sir, I got it. Even if texas calculation wrong, which Crss value should I consider to calculate  Q ? Should I consider what is given in the datasheet which is 50 pF approximately or any other way ?  @Tim Williams

Again, don't need capacitance. Use charge. It's already given. Most of the charge is at low voltages, as you can see from the capacitance curve, the above waveform, etc. Charge varies little with Vds (unfortunately they don't show a range, but they do show a value close to your use case, 300V).
