Problem with H-bridge circuit inverting power to electromagnet. The transistors are burning up, but I don't see the problem
Background:
I am using an H-bridge configuration (w/ flyback circuit) to invert the power to an electromagnet.
I made the system with all NMOS transistors (Q1-Q4). It is running at a max of 300 A @ 30 V. They were inexpensive and (to my knowledge) I don't need the voltage robustness of IGBTs for this application. The transistors are rated to Vds = 80 V. I'm running two transistors in parallel for each one shown in the circuit diagram below.

I am applying gate voltages off-board with 15 V AC/DC power supplies that reference the source of the transistors. The diodes (D1 - D4) withstand repetitive peak voltages of 600 V and are overrated on current.
Problem:
When testing without a significant load, the board operates fine. It inverts 300 A with no issue and Ids linearly increases with Vds. When testing on the electromagnet (with a higher resistance), it appears that between V_PS1 = 3 - 5 V another circuit opens up.The transistors burn up when increasing the current beyond 100 A.
Here is the IV Curve:

Troubleshooting:
All of the transistors share the same heat-sink. I tested the resistance between the contacts of each component and found no shorts (all Mega Ohm).
My best guess at this point is that a body diode of a transistor is turning on, but I don't see any situations when Vs > Vd.
If you have any ideas where I went wrong, I'd greatly appreciate your time helping me out. I'm primarily asking if the circuit looks correct. If something went wrong during manufacture then that's a different issue.

Can you confirm you don't have shoot-through (cross-conduction when high-side and low-side transistors are on at the same time. Even briefly)?

Yes I can confirm there is no shoot through from the control side (200 ms delay between turning the relays off and then on). I don't believe shoot-through is related to this issue because it occurs during a static operation (no switching).

How does $V_{DS}$ get to be 3-5 V? $R_{DS}$ is supposed to be under 2 $m\Omega$, so it seems like it should not get that large.

Thermal issue? As the case temperature heats up, the transistors can’t handle much more than 100 Amps….Diagram 2 in the datasheet.

Your schematic shows mechanical switches controlling the MOSFET gates. Could you post your actual circuit please? I would like to know how the gates are driven.

Did you try lower resistor values, e.g. 1 kohm, for R3-R6?

Doesn't seem to be anything immediately suspicious here. Have you measured the MOSFET voltages directly (at each device), near/in the current limit condition (4V, >70A operating region)? Anything oscillating on the oscilloscope? || FYI, those diodes are plain PN-junction rectifiers, not schottky -- small correction.

at 3v Vds, you can only do about 30A to keep it inside the safe operating area.

Did you try moving your electromagnet further away from the circuit? There is a "Lorentz Force" which modulates FET Drain current in strong magnetic field. I have no idea how substantial this effect is, but moving the electromagnet further away should show a change if the effect is significant.

Is PS2 floating or referenced to PS1?

What are the switches? What controls them?

"two transistors in parallel for each one shown in the circuit diagram below." Please update your schematic to show the full circuit. Do you have individual gate resistors?

@rpm2718 I mistyped. I should have said when the PS1 voltage > 3 - 4 V. I will edit the question. Most of that is dropping over the 100 mOhm load, not transistors. The voltage across the load decreases when the PS1 voltage > 3 V. The system is actively cooled and can function at 300 A with no resistance on the load.

@winny Okay I will update the circuit in the next hour. The switches are solid state relays from an Ethernet controlled relay board. The transistors in parallel do not have individual resistors.

@dandavis I mistyped Vds when I should have written PS1 voltage. I have edited the post.

@TimWilliams Thanks Tim. I will go through the steps of probing the circuit to look for the issue. Before I went down that route, I wanted to check first that the circuit didn't have anything obvious wrong. It sounds like referencing PS2 to PS1, looking closely at the solid state relays controlling the gates, and probing the transistor contacts are good places to start.

@tobalt It is floating, but I think you are onto something and they should share a reference. Thanks!

If I take that gate drive circuit literally, then with those 50k ohm gate resistors the turn off is going to be very slow, discharging the miller effect capacitance.  And as we know that capacitance gets bigger at higher drain voltage. This might result in shoot-through, or maybe just much increased switching losses.

"The switches are solid state relays" Do you have sufficient dead time between turning off one pair of MOSFETS and turning on the complementary pair? Also, are you sure the SSRs don't transmit a phantom voltage even when they are off? SSRs are not like mechanical relays in that respect. The result could be all MOSFETs left "on", which obviously will kill them.

@electrogas Lower* at higher Vds.

When you have an inductor, and you saturate it, the current exponentially rises past that point. Is the electromagnet in saturation?

@Tim Williams Lower miller capacitance at higher Vds????

@electrogas Yes, Crss drops as Vds goes up; this is typical from old planar to modern superjunction types. Particularly in modern types, the ratio is large enough that the gate plateau ends at fairly low Vds. You may find this of interest: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/726393/mosfet-transconductance-question/726565#726565

(300 A without a significant load?!) Did you test each half-bridge on its own?

Are you sure you are turning off the transistors before turning on the other pair? Try to observe this on a scope. I suggest: put one probe on load+, one on load-, and the other 2 on gates of transistors you are ABOUT to turn ON.

How fast are you switching them? How fast can the SSR go? Please post an oscillogram for turn-on, turn-off and direction reversal.

The switching speed is very slow compared to most transistor circuits. The high end is around 1 Hz.
@MathKeepsMeBusy I think you could be right about the SSR not turning off all the way. I will check that next. Thanks.

I think one design problem is that we are not talking about an inductivity here but an electromagnet.  Where is the difference?  The point of an electromagnet is that it does significant work by closing and opening a magnetic circuit.
When the magnet has attracted pieces of iron, the inductivity of the ensemble is hugely increased because they close the magnetic circuit.  That means that the capacitor is insufficient for capturing the resulting flyback energy when the magnet is switched off.  Now how much of a flyback voltage is the circuit good for?  The body diodes of your MOSFETs clamp the voltage inside of the supply lines.  If the flyback voltage exceeds the supply, it will discharge across two body diodes.
That may be bad news as the body diodes are not intended for significant currents.
Actually, I see that your problem occurs with "PS_1 between 3 and 5V".  PS_2 preloads the flyback dump capacitor so that the dump circuit just starts working at voltages larger than 36V (that is so that the flyback voltage clamp will consume significant energy, essentially by transferring it to the PS2 power supply).
But your body diodes will clamp the flyback voltage to PS_1, so your whole flyback circuit is essentially dead and instead you dump everything through your transistors at comparatively low voltage, meaning extended amounts of time.

If I understand you correctly, adding diodes on the source side of Q1 and Q3 will allow the flyback circuit to work as intended.

@DanielMcCulley Probably, but diodes cause drop-voltage and thus will consume more power than the MOSFETs.  What you can do is put diodes in parallel with the MOSFETs.  There are MOSFETs with a higher-forward-voltage body diode that can be protected by paralleling them with an ordinary silicon power diode as bypass.

Sounds like transient issue. Try to measure the voltages at switching time (switching off). You might need to add diodes to prevent voltage spikes during switching. You indicate your load has inductive nature, when you switch the current through the load can not react to voltage instantly due to inductive nature.
Let's assume the system starts at a state where load+ is 30V and load - is 0V.
When you switch and disconnect the 30V from load +, just before you apply 0V to load +, the current would flow through the load and make load + 0V. But it can not that quickly as the olad is inductor. So load + remains 30V. And then you switch the 0V to load +, which makes all the charge flow through the q2 instantly, as it becomes short (and transient current can't flow through inductor).
The current is basically 30V/r_ds_on which is probably huge, since rds_on is usually in miliohm range, if it's 300 mili ohm, the transient current is 100A.
